# How to convert a static html into razor view in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following simple bootstrap form:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Register</h3>
<br>
<form action="/User/Register">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">

        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label">MAC</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2 positioned_relative">
            <span class="add-new-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="add_mac"> </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mac_addr" placeholder="Enter MAC">
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group row new_mac_wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="new_mac_container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-1">Register</button>

</form>
```

I want to convert this into razor view as follows:

```
@model RouterManagement.Models.UserViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3 class="pull-left">Register</h3> <br />

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mac, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mac, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mac, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-1" />
            </div>
        </div>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

And for this conversion I get the following rendered HTML:

```
<form action="/Users/Register" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="IZ_dvCy7QtB1VsoqQGh6x_Yzr1DME9V6LjKs1Fi8KL6KxOoKNNvFlH6mdw8yD4xIj-LKaUXFsNZndDTeHOa8xCVZPdu7b8qNXeL05IdIyiQ1">        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" for="Name">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" for="Email">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" for="Password">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Password" name="Password" type="text" value="">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" for="Mac">Mac</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2">

                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Mac" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-1">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

This is approximately close to my static html. If you pay a deep attention you can see some additional html generated in case of razor view. I am okay with this additional html but why my design has been broken. I checked for css and js files. All are okay, but there is something related to razor conversion only. Any Idea?

N.S: I am switching from PHP to ASP. So I am apologizing if my question is not standard to ask here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is it that you are claiming is 'broken'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief - this two HTML's are not the same.
They differ in a few things:
- in original bootstrap form, you have inputs for Name, Email, and Mac - in generated you have Name, Email, Password, and Mac.

Then in original, each input tag is wrapped in div with **class = "form-group row"** in generated only first input has these, and the rest have only "form-group". Then in original inside MAC input group, you have div with **class="col-sm-10 col-md-2 positioned_relative"** and in original, there is no such thing.

Also in original, you have div with **class="form-group row new_mac_wrapper"** and in the generated code there is none.
I will not go further into details but as you can see you have two different code - hard to tell what is breaking things without a chance to see the whole project.

However, the suggestion is to start little by little - start with just one field (Name) in original and on generated code.
See the differences and only when there is none keep up adding and comparing one field at the time.

Comment: OP is already aware that the html is different as stated in the question - this in no way answers the question.